# Help rearranging limit of double sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am trying to manipulate the expression

\begin{align*}
(1 - \gamma)\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{h = 1}^n \sum_{t = 0}^{h - 1} j_t \gamma^{h - 1}.
\end{align*}

I know that $\gamma \in (0, 1)$, so $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^n = \frac{1}{1 - \gamma}$, and I also know that $j_t \in (0, 1)$ for all $t \in \mathbb N$, so I know that $\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^t j_t = M < \infty$.

I **want** to do the following:

\begin{align*}
(1 - \gamma)\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{h = 1}^n \sum_{t = 0}^{h - 1} j_t \gamma^{h - 1} &= (1 - \gamma)\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} \sum_{h = t}^{n - 1} j_t \gamma^h \quad \text{(rearrange partial sum)}\\
&= (1 - \gamma)\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} j_t \sum_{h = t}^{n - 1} \gamma^h \quad \text{(pull out term)}\\
&= (1 - \gamma) \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} j_t \sum_{h = t}^{\infty} \gamma^h \quad \text{(most unsure about this part)}\\
&= (1 - \gamma) \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} j_t \gamma^t\sum_{h = 0}^{\infty} \gamma^h \quad \text{(pull out term)}\\
&= \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} j_t \gamma^t \quad \text{(geometric series)}\\
&= M \quad \text{(by assumption)}.
\end{align*}

**Question: Is this all legitimate?** I *think* it is, by some kind of argument involving doubly-indexed sums and absolute convergence. But I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's legitimate but you need to explain more the "most unsure about this part" step.

You're absolutely correct that there's a doubly indexed sum here which converges absolutely. You could more explicitly define a doubly indexed sum as follows. Let $a_{t,h}=j_t \gamma^h$ if $h\geq t$, with $a_{t,h}=0$ otherwise, for non-negative indices $t,h$. With this notation, you're then trying to evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} \sum_{h = 0}^{n - 1} a_{t,h}$$ The doubly indexed sum $\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{h=0}^\infty a_{t,h}$ converges absolutely (to $M$), as you've shown in your working after the "most unsure about this part" step. So, the sum can be evaluated in any order, and in particular $$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{h=0}^\infty a_{t,h}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} \sum_{h = 0}^{n - 1} a_{t,h}$$ This result is explicitly stated as Theorem 2.8.1 in [Understanding Analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-2712-8) by Stephen Abbott.

You could also avoid all this by explicit evaluation as follows.
$$\begin{align*}
(1-\gamma)\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} j_t \sum_{h = t}^{n - 1} \gamma^h
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} j_t \gamma^t (1-\gamma^{n-t}) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t = 0}^{n - 1} j_t (\gamma^t-\gamma^n)\\
&= M-\lim_{n \to \infty}\gamma^n \sum_{t=0}^{n-1} j_t
\end{align*}$$

The remaining limit on the RHS is zero because the terms are bounded by $\gamma^n n$ which converges to zero if $\gamma<1$.